# How to create different branches from a certain branch

Tags: git

I just created the default repository pointing to `origin/master`
I would like to create a `release` and a `production` branch

Should I create a git branches from origin/master itself

e.g. `git branch release` and `git branch production`

or

Should I create origin/production from origin/release

```
git branch release
git push origin release
```

and

```
git checkout release
git branch production
```

What would be the prefered approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the concepts here.

It doesn't matter from which branch you create the new branch, the most important point is from which commit you want it to start.

Branches and tags in git are just a pointer to an specific commit (which has a history represented in a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)). The difference is that tags usually stay static in time, and branches usually change as the coding progress.

So basically, when you get a point in the history where you have your first release, create a `release` branch pointing that commit. (I'd recommend to tag it too.)

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, probably you really don't need branches, and tags would be enough. I'd recommend you to read [pro git book](http://git-scm.com/book) to get more familiar with the concepts of branching ([pro git's "Tagging" chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging)) and tagging ([pro git's "What a Branch Is" chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is)) before making these decisions about your repository.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it doesn’t matter. Branch references (local or remote) are just that: *references* to a commit. Doing

```
git checkout master
git branch release
git branch production
```

or

```
git checkout master
git branch release
git checkout release
git branch production
```

are exactly equivalent because in the end they are all just references to the same commit (you can verify this by running [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) with each branch name and comparing the result). Git keeps no record of what branch a branch was created from, instead only knowing what the most-recent common commit between them was.

Answer (score 0):

The `remotes/origin/...` branches are remote tracking branches. You should not manipulate these directly, they server as tracking the branches of remote repositories. (E.g they get updated when you do `git fetch <remote-repo-name>`.)

To answer your question, you should create the release and production branches from your local master (so I assume below that the current branch is master):

```
git checkout -b release
<do some work>
git add .
git commit -m <commit message>
git push -u origin release
```

`git checkout -b` creates a new branch and switches to it in one instruction. `git push -u` pushes to the remote and branch and adds an upstream reference so when you pull and push to that branch you no longer have to define them.

The same workflow is applicable for the production branch (although master is usually considered as production-ready)

Comment: I’m not really sure the OP ever suggested directly manipulating remote references, only checking them out (e.g. `git checkout origin/master`), which is fine.